# Could not find configuration node: marketingDefinitionSearch/indexConfigurations/marketingDefinitionLuceneIndexConfiguration

Tags: xdb, content-search, lucene

Getting Following Exception in CD Server where Xdb is enabled and rest all configs are disabled. Master Database has been turned to Pub Database(Live Database).

```
3248 21:44:46 ERROR Error loading hook: <hook          type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Hooks.Initializer, Sitecore.ContentSearch" patch:source="Sitecore.ContentSearch.config" xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" />
        Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
    Message: Could not find configuration node: marketingDefinitionSearch/indexConfigurations/marketingDefinitionLuceneIndexConfiguration
    Source: Sitecore.Kernel
       at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.GetConfigNode(String xpath, Boolean assert)
       at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(String configPath, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
       at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromReference(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
       at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper)
       at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
       at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.GetInnerObject(XmlNode paramNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
       at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.AssignProperties(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Object obj, Boolean assert, Boolean deferred, IFactoryHelper helper)
       at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper)
       at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
       at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.GetInnerObject(XmlNode paramNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
       at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.AssignProperties(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Object obj, Boolean assert, Boolean deferred, IFactoryHelper helper)
       at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper)
       at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
       at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(String configPath, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
       at Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentSearchManager.get_SearchConfiguration()
       at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Hooks.Initializer.Initialize()
       at Sitecore.Events.Hooks.HookManager.LoadAll()
```

Though this is background error from log and I don't see any visible implication of this as of now. Any clue why it is so. You can find the showconfig output [here](https://1drv.ms/f/s!AjgrI9CsuLVVkCRviwrYe0iSynzB)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're missing `Sitecore.Marketing.Lucene.IndexConfiguration.config` from the `App_Config` directory.

Copy this file from the clean Sitecore install.

Comment: @MarekMusiealk you are right , somehow i disabled that configuration file while doing configuring CD instance.